# How to construct interface which creates Entry<X, Y>

Tags: java, generics

I need to create an interface called `SecureHeaderCreator` which creates `Entry<X, Y>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
interface SecureHeaderCreator<X, Y> {
    public Entry<X, Y> createEntry(X x, Y y); // whatever args you need to create an Entry
}
```

or maybe you want an implementation of this create method within the interface? You can have this as a `default` method;

```
interface SecureHeaderCreator<X, Y> {
    default Entry<X, Y> createEntry(X x, Y y) {
        return Entry.of(x, y); //some Entry builder
    }
}
```